# ActiveX cannot run .exe without privilege elevation

Tags: windows, delphi, internet-explorer, activex, uac

We developed an ActiveX form control to be installed in IE8+.
This control checks for a registry key then download and install a small setup if needed.
For administrator everything work as expected on Windows 7 and 8 with any IE version 8+.

With non-admin users, the control runs (it must be installed by admin, but it's ok), it downloads the executable `client_setup.exe` in path C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Low\ but when it tries to run executable (shellexec or createprocess produce same result) an administrative account is required and UAC elevation prompt appears.

If non-admin user download and install same setup, no administration privilege is required (we declared this in exe manifest). This setup is entirely installed in user profile and HKCU registry.

I understand that ActiveX control runs with low privileges like IE process. But why elevation is required in this case? Our setup do not requires privileges.

I tried to add ActiveX control in Low Rights elevation policy exceptions here

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy
```

but still UAC prompt appears.

I want to allow to run this setup for all users. We can run once as administrator a script to give permission for the whole system. Can someone help with this task?

TEST 1

As non-admin user, I tried to manually install the .exe downloaded by the ActiveX and I get a system error, cannot write to temp directory. If I download the same exe file with Internet Explorer I can install this with no problems.

I checked with ICACLS and on exe downloaded by ActiveX control there is a Mandatory Label\Low Mandatory Level:(I)(NW)

TEST 2

Site was added to trusted sites as Taxilian suggested. As non-admin user, ActiveX now saves .exe setup to C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Temp (no Low), .exe hasn't low level label anymore. But still, CreateProcess raises UAC prompt and fails.

This is my CreateProcess code. It's Delphi code but it should be readable.

```
function RunProcess(FileName: string; ShowCmd: DWORD; wait: Boolean; ProcID: PDWORD): Longword;
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo), #0);
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := ShowCmd;
  if not CreateProcess(nil,
    @Filename[1],
    nil,
    nil,
    False,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
    nil,
    nil,
    StartupInfo,
    ProcessInfo)
    then
    Result := WAIT_FAILED
  else
  begin
    if wait = FALSE then
    begin
      if ProcID <> nil then
        ProcID^ := ProcessInfo.dwProcessId;
      result := WAIT_FAILED;
      exit;
    end;
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, Result);
  end;
  if ProcessInfo.hProcess <> 0 then
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
  if ProcessInfo.hThread <> 0 then
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
end;
```

This is .exe manifest. It is a simple setup that copies some files to user profile and add a registry key in HKCU.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity name="JR.Inno.Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32" />
    <description>Inno Setup</description>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <windowsSettings>
            <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
        </windowsSettings>
    </application>
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />
        </application>
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you use `CreateProcess` to try to launch the executable?  Does `CreateProcess` return an error code?  Have you tried using Process Monitor to track the sequence of events?

Comment: CreateProcess returns error code 1 which doesn't make sense to me. In fact CreateProcess fails due to UAC prompt.

Comment: Maybe out of topic, but: 
- why are you calling `CloseHandle` event when `CreateProcess` fails?
- you are not calling `CloseHandle` when `Wait=False`
- if your `Filename` will contain spaces, and it won't be double-quoted, then you it will fail

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Filename is already double quoted elsewhere. CloseHandle is called only when there's something to close. It should be ok.

Comment: CreateProcess isn't supposed to be generating a UAC prompt in the first place.  If elevation is required, CreateProcess should fail immediately.  Are you sure the UAC prompt isn't being generated *after* the executable has already been started?

Comment: Hard to tell. I cannot debug as non-admin user inside internet explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows UAC uses some heuristics to detect installers.

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uac/archive/2006/01/13/512776.aspx :

> The O/S makes a decision that the application looks like an installer
>   or updater and will automatically invoke elevation to run the program
>   with administrative permissions/privileges when a user runs it. This
>   decision is based on a heuristic. Here are some of the heuristic
>   detection points, although this list is not exhaustive:
>
> 1. File name detection – looks for the words “setup”, “update”,
>      “install” in the filename

Our setup name is `client_setup.exe`, so UAC is triggered even if it's not needed, asking for administration privileges, totally ignoring exe manifest. Let's call this a feature.

It was enough to rename `client_setup.exe` to `client.exe`, then run it. No UAC prompt appears and setup completes successfully.

This looks like a recent change from Microsoft. As recent as 4 months ago, our setup was launched without errors.

Comment: The line `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker"/>` should be enough to bypass the heuristic.  I think the `trustInfo` element must be in the **v2** namespace, not the **v3** namespace.

Comment: It seems that exe name overrides manifest executionlevel. Why v2 instead v3? Some docs?

Comment: Well, I could ask you the same thing.  Did you try using **v2**?  From [some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545961.aspx) [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531381.aspx) [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1c2fch.aspx) I can find, the samples go like this: **v2** for `trustInfo` and `security`, **v3** for `requestedPrivileges` and `requestedExecutionLevel`.

Comment: We read different documents. In those I've found examples are with v3. Do you know what's the difference?

Comment: Not really.  The only clue I have about it is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd970597.aspx), but I think this is the actual schema for [application manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191.aspx).

Comment: I tried modifying manifest and behaviour is the same. So I guess this is not an issue here. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the activex control that has to be [registered to run as a medium integrity process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wpm_elebp), it's the EXE that you are launching from said activex control.

Comment: But how do you explain that when activeX saves exe this has Low Mandatory Level set? Seems to me that ActiveX is running as low level.

Comment: Yes, ActiveX is always running as a low integrity process if you have UAC enabled.  There is *nothing* you can do about that.

Comment: So you confirm that there is absolutely nothing an admin can do to elevate a specific ActiveX from low to medium? Some registry settings, IE settings, domain policy?

Comment: You could add the domain it's running on as a trusted domain

Comment: (add it to the trusted sites list I mean)

Comment: I added site to trusted site as you suggested. Now C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp is used (and not Low), .exe has no more low level label, but still UAC prompt appears. I will add this to question.